# How to read a csv and write to a new CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, parsing

python 2.7
input csv file

```
person  alpha   beta    gamma
alex            1       2
bob     2               1
zac     1       2
```

output format

```
Person  data            qty<2
alex    beta,gamma      beta
bob     alpha,gamma     gamma
zac     alpha,beta      alpha
```

Comment: Please properly format your code, and post the formats as text.

Comment: Please clarify what the issue is, and provide a [mcve]. As an aside, why are you using Python 2?

Comment: HI, im using python 2.7, as m new to stackoverflow m unable to make the proper edit to show how the data is looking

Comment: @Roy Yeah, I tried to edit the code, but I'm not entirely sure what it's supposed to look like. Why can't you share it? _im using python 2.7_ Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, I was asking why you are using that version.

Comment: @Roy don't use tabs, for one.  They don't work well on a website.  One problem with your code is that it doesn't specify tabs as a delimiter.  The  CSV default is comma.

Comment: thank you scott AMC for editing mark  The input file looks like the above top code, every data is string, even the numbers. I should get the output with the three columns as i mentioned. I am not able to write the if statement to calculate data and qty<2 column.

Comment: @Roy _The input file looks like the above top code, every data is string, even the numbers._ Where does this data come from? Do you control the source? _I am not able to write the if statement to calculate data and qty<2 column._ Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have a csv file named "x", in which I have the input data(person, alpha,beta,gamma), I need to read this file and write to a new csv named "y"  file with 3 columns((person, data, qty<2).

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what the issue is. Where does this data come from? Do you control the source?

Comment: AMC- sorry for not able to be clear, Mark Tolonen answer perferctly works fine to the data I gave.  but it doesnt work with the actual data I have, I will change the question input and output and add some details to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you given the following input (tab-delimited):

```
person  alpha   beta    gamma
alex            1       2
bob     2               1
zac     1       2
```

Code:

```
#!python2
import csv
import os

# open in binary mode per Python 2 csv docs
with open('x.csv','rb') as fin:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(fin,delimiter='\t')
    headers = next(csv_reader)
    item_names = headers[1:]    # collect names of data columns

    with open('y.csv','wb') as fout:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(fout,delimiter='\t')
        csv_writer.writerow(['Person','data','qty<2'])

        for row in csv_reader:
            person = row[0]
            items = row[1:] # list of the alpha/beta/gamma data

            data = []   # collect the names of non-empty data
            qtylt2 = [] # collect the names of <2 data

            for i,item in enumerate(items):
                if item:
                    data.append(item_names[i])
                    if int(item) < 2:
                        qtylt2.append(item_names[i])

            csv_writer.writerow([person,','.join(data),','.join(qtylt2)])
```

Output:

```
Person  data            qty<2
alex    beta,gamma      beta
bob     alpha,gamma     gamma
zac     alpha,beta      alpha
```